# Wxpython callbacks

Tags: wxpython

I have 3 controls in my frame -

1. A list box that has a list of employees name from the employee table.
2. A text box that accepts new employee name
3. A command button on click will insert a new name in the employee table.

Requirement:

Once I press the submit button after inserting a new row the list box should be automatically refreshed with the new name.

How do I accomplish this task ?

I'm successfully able to create the controls and bind a on click event and insert a row. But unable to refresh the list box.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the ListBox's SetItems method:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.choices = ["George Lucas"]
        self.lbox = wx.ListBox(self, choices=self.choices)
        self.new_emp = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        addBtn = wx.Button(self, label="Add Employee")
        addBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.addEmployee)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.lbox, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.new_emp, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(addBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def addEmployee(self, event):
        """"""
        emp = self.new_emp.GetValue()
        self.choices.append(emp)
        self.lbox.SetItems(self.choices)
        self.new_emp.SetValue("")

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Employee")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```